# Wordpress running on Nginx Loadbalancer error "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Tags: nginx, centos7, load-balancing, wordpress

So I have this setup for my wordpress.

All servers run on Centos 7
MariaDB 10.4.17
Php-FPM 7.4
PHP 7.4
NginX

Server 1, the Front Load Balancing server
Server 2-3-4 the wordpress application served with NginX
Server 4 MariaDB

The Nginx loadbalance setup run fine with standard info.php on each of the server 2-3-4.  They switch around using the round robin.

The wordpress on its own run fine on server 2-3-4.  I have to change the site URL and home URL of the wordpress in the wp-options DB to reflect the ip address of the server.  So for example if I'm testing wp server 2, the site url and home url is pointed to server 2.

The second I combined all of the servers 2-3-4 under the LB with the wordpress, I got this error "The page isn’t redirecting properly".  I'm not quite sure whether there's a certain settings that needs to be done in order to make the WP works under the Nginx load balancer.  Any advise is how to fix the issue?  Please help?

My LB Nginx config.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    root         /var/www/wp;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;



log_format upstreamlog '$server_name to : $upstream_addr [$request] '
'upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time '
'msec $msec request_time $request_time';

upstream big_server_com {
    ip_hash;
    server 192.168.1.32;
    server 192.168.1.33;
    server 192.168.1.34;



}

    server {
       server_name myserver.net wp.myserver.net;

#acces_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


     fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/wp.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
     proxy_pass      http://big_server_com;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            }
            index  index.php;
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
#    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem; # managed by Certbot

}     
   server {
    if ($host = myserver.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = myserver.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen       80;
     server_name myserver.net wp.myserver.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
}
```

My Wordpress wp-config

```
<?php

define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'admin' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '*************' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', '192.168.1.34' );

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
    define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );

/**#@-*/


$table_prefix = 'wp_';
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';


if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) 
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

NginX Configuration on the backend server

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    root         /var/www/wp;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
     listen 192.168.1.32:80;
        server_name  wp2.myserver.net;
    location ~ \.php$ {
     fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/wp.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            }
            index  index.php;
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    } 

}
```

Comment: What URL did you visit? What redirect did you receive?

Comment: So the setup on the site URL and home URL is http://wp.myserver.net and the setup on the 3 application servers where WP is hosted are wp2.myserver.net, wp3.myserver.net, wp4.myserver.net.  The URL on the browser I typed is the LB server address which is wp.myserver.net and the redirect error I got from firefox was "The page isn’t redirecting properly" and from Chrome was "wp.myserver.net redirected you too many times".

Comment: I don't get any redirects, just a blank page. Looking at the requests in Firefox web developer tools it looks like a parked domain that belongs to someone else. So I think you didn't give the real domain name. If you don't want to do this, it will be more difficult to figure out and you will need to provide **significantly** more detail. Open the web developer tools and look at the URLs of the 301 redirects and the locations to which they redirect. Also look to see if there is an X-Powered-By response header.

Comment: I can see the 301 is coming from WordPress and it is trying to redirect to https. Your load balancer config looks OK (except for the spurious `fastcgi_` stuff that doesn't belong there). It's time to look at the config of the backend web servers.

Comment: What can I provide on the backend config other than the wp-config that I had already posted?

Comment: Also, any other suggestion on the fastcgi that I can turn off?

Comment: The nginx configuration?

Comment: I have added the NginX backend configuration on one of the server.